# Return highest values in a vector with multiple conditionals

Tags: r, dplyr, summary

I have these example data

```
Data <- structure(list(IndID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "56", "58", "59", "60", "63"), class = "factor"), 
    Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("BHS", 
    "MTG"), class = "factor"), Season = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L), .Label = c("Summer", "Winter"), class = "factor"), 
    Percent = c(0.992, 0.992, 0.996, 0.976, 0.995, 0.871, 0.996, 
    0.996, 0.916, 0.875, 0.652, 0.802, 0.964, 0.673, 0.956, 0.879, 
    0.972, 0.782, 0.968, 0.832)), .Names = c("IndID", "Species", 
"Season", "Percent"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which look like this

```
> head(Data)
  IndID Species Season Percent
1     1     BHS Summer   0.992
2     1     BHS Winter   0.992
3     2     BHS Summer   0.996
4     2     BHS Winter   0.976
5     3     BHS Winter   0.995
6     3     BHS Summer   0.871
```

There are 10 unique individuals that belong to one of two species (BHS  or  MTG).  For each individual (IndID), there is a Percent value for each Season (Winter and Summer).

For each Species, I want to select the two individuals that have the highest average Percent value.

**EDIT** Also see my note below.  I did not post a specific outcome because there are multiple that would work for my needs. Because I need a measure Percent for each Season, I thought taking the average of the Percent would be the best approach to select the top individuals.  Percent was measured for each season, but I want to select the highest rank IndID.  I could also rank IndID by the sum of Percent (rather than average).

In addition to the 2nd chunk of code posted by @akrun, a vector of 4 IndIDs (the two top ranked for each species) would also have been a fine output.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: To make clear what you are asking, please post desired output.

Comment: Hello, hi.  Please do post the desired result so the people being downvoted for attempting to answer your unclear question can know if their answers are correct or not. Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you would like a `dplyr` solution (from the tag), we group the data by 'Species', order 'Percent' column in descending (`arrange`) and use `slice` to get the first two rows per each 'Species'

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      arrange(desc(Percent)) %>%
      slice(1:2)
#    IndID Species Season Percent
#1     2     BHS Summer   0.996
#2     4     BHS Summer   0.996
#3    60     MTG Summer   0.972
#4    63     MTG Summer   0.968
```

An expected output would have been easier.  If this is based on average percentage, we group by 'Species' and 'IndID', create a new column 'AvgPercent' based on the `mean` of 'Percent', we group by 'Species', order the 'AvgPercent' column in descending order and get the 1st two 'IndID'

```
 Data %>%
      group_by(Species, IndID) %>%
      mutate(AvgPercent=mean(Percent))  %>%
      group_by(Species) %>% 
      arrange(desc(AvgPercent)) %>% 
      slice(1:4) %>% 
      select(-AvgPercent) %>%
      filter(!duplicated(IndID))
 #   IndID Species Season Percent
 #1     4     BHS Summer   0.996
 #2     1     BHS Summer   0.992
 #3    59     MTG Summer   0.956
 #4    63     MTG Summer   0.968
```

Comment: Very slick.  I knew the answer was likely in dplyr.  Thanks for the new functions!

Comment: This doesn't use an *average* Percent between the summer and winter.

Comment: @bourbaki4481472  In that case `Data %>% group_by(Species, IndID) %>% mutate(AvgPercent=mean(Percent))  %>% goup_by(Species) %>% arrange(desc(AvgPercent)) %>% slice(1:2) %>% select(-AvgPerent)`

Comment: @B.Davis - Please tell us if this gives you your desired result. There is a troll among us.

Comment: The 2nd chunk of code in the answer above works well.  I did not specify an output as multiple are possible for my desired need.  by changing the slice argument to 1:4 I can get the top 2 individuals for each species.  What is the 2L argument to slice() edited above?

Comment: @B.Davis I changed to `1:4` and removed the duplicate IndID, now it is 2 rows per each Species.  The `2L` argument is selecting only the 2nd row for each `Species`.  `L` is not required.  It is just an integer representation.

Comment: @B.Davis Yes, it is based on the averagepercent.  So, it will be different than the first one.

Comment: @B.Davis When I checked for the `IndID` 60, the Summer and Winter values are 0.972 and 0.782, causing the average to be 0.877.

Comment: @akrun,  all looks goon in your 2nd code chunk.  My previous comment was incorrect and has been removed.  Thanks again.

Comment: Rather than using arrange, it's a bit more efficient to do `row_number(desc(Percent)) <= 2`

Answer (score 3):

Another option making use of `tidyr`'s `gather` and `spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Data %>% 
    spread(Season, Percent) %>% 
    mutate(avg = (Summer + Winter)/2) %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    arrange(desc(avg)) %>% 
    top_n(2)

#  IndID Species Summer Winter    avg
#1     4     BHS  0.996  0.996 0.9960
#2     1     BHS  0.992  0.992 0.9920
#3    59     MTG  0.956  0.879 0.9175
#4    63     MTG  0.968  0.832 0.9000
```

Here is a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)

setDT(Data)[, avg := mean(Percent), by = .(IndID, Species)]
Data[Data[Season=="Summer", .I[order(avg, decreasing = T)[1:2]], by = Species]$V1]

#   IndID Species Season Percent    avg
#1:     4     BHS Summer   0.996 0.9960
#2:     1     BHS Summer   0.992 0.9920
#3:    59     MTG Summer   0.956 0.9175
#4:    63     MTG Summer   0.968 0.9000
```

Answer (score 2):

Or with `plyr`

```
 ddply(Data, "Species", function(x) sort(x[, "Percent"], T))[, 1:3]
  Species    V1    V2
1     BHS 0.996 0.996
2     MTG 0.972 0.968
```

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` solution (`library(data.table)`).

`d <- data.table(Data)` Wraps your `Data` into a `data.table` object.

Make a new table that also lists the average Percent (between Summer and Winter for each individual).

`t <- d[, meanPercent := mean(Percent), by = IndID]`

Merge some rows based on `IndID`

`t <- t[, .SD[, list(Species, meanPercent)][1], by = IndID]`

Finally select the top two individuals by the average Percent for each Species.

`t[order(-meanPercent)][Species == "BHS"][1:2]`

`t[order(-meanPercent)][Species == "MTG"][1:2]`